# React useState being ignored

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a small React app where you can click on a piece of text to replace it with an input field, to allow you to edit it.

The problem is that the `EditableText` component does not seem to want to display the `editingText` state in the input field.

See example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-ellis-kyrdb

For posterity, the code for the main app is:

```
export default function App() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "fred"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "jim"
    }
  ]);
  const [activeCat, setActiveCat] = useState({});
  const handleClick = (cat, e) => {
    setActiveCat(cat);
  };
  const saveName = (newName) => {
    // save this cat's new name...
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="catMenu">
        {cats.map((row) => (
          <div
            className="catItem"
            key={row.id}
            onClick={(e) => handleClick(row, e)}
          >
            {row.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="activeCat">
        <h2>
          <EditableText text={activeCat.name} saveText={saveName} />
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and for the `EditableText` component:

```
const EditableText = (props) => {
  const { text, saveText } = props;
  const [editing, setEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editingText, setEditingText] = useState(text);
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeydown = (e) => {
      if (editing) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
          // Enter key pressed
          saveText(editingText);
          setEditing(false);
        }
        if (e.keyCode === 27) {
          // Escape key pressed
          setEditingText(text);
          setEditing(false);
        }
      }
    };
    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);
    };
  }, [text, saveText, editing, editingText]);
  return (
    <div>
      <div
        onClick={() => setEditing(true)}
        className={`et-${editing ? "hidden" : "active"}`}
      >
        {text}
      </div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={editingText}
        onChange={(e) => setEditingText(e.target.value)}
        className={`et-input-${editing ? "active" : "hidden"}`}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditableText;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `useEffect` to listen to `text` prop change, you only use it as initial empty value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setEditingText(text);
}, [text]);
```

[image: Edit dreamy-shadow-vicxr]